# Why am I getting '502 status error' while making a HTTP request to REST API?

Tags: php, rest

I am trying to fetch some data from a REST API, I have properly specified the parameters and even my access token is valid yet I am not getting back the expected response, I am making the following HTTP request :

```php
//set parameters
$paramRequest = array(
"title" => "Sample Daily meeting",
"agenda" => "Sample Agenda",
"password" => "BgJep@43",
"start" => "2020-07-01 15:00:00",
"end" => "2020-07-01 16:00:00",
"timezone" => "Asia/Shanghai",
"recurrence" => "FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=1;COUNT=10",
"enabledAutoRecordMeeting" => false,
"allowAnyUserToBeCoHost" => false,
);

$cURLConnection = curl_init("https://webexapis.com/v1/meetings");
curl_setopt($cURLConnection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $paramRequest);
curl_setopt($cURLConnection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($cURLConnection, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                                            'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                                            'Connection: Keep-Alive',
                                            'Authorization: Bearer ' . $token 
                                            ));
//send HTTP POST request
$apiResponse = curl_exec($cURLConnection);
curl_close($cURLConnection);

// $apiResponse - available data from the API request
$jsonArrayResponse = json_decode($apiResponse);

//display response
print_r($jsonArrayResponse);
```

I am receiving the following response from the API:

```php
stdClass Object ( [message] => The server, while acting as a gateway or proxy, received an invalid response from the upstream server it accessed in attempting to fulfill the request. [errors] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [description] => The server, while acting as a gateway or proxy, received an invalid response from the upstream server it accessed in attempting to fulfill the request. ) ) [trackingId] => ROUTER_5EFC3CCD-C466-01BB-0100-AC12DED20100 )
```

Comment: `The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) 502 Bad Gateway server error response code indicates that the server, while acting as a gateway or proxy, received an invalid response from the upstream server.`

Comment: Usual reason in my experience is a nginx server in front of a apache server, and occasionally one gets confused and the whole thing has a hiccup for a few seconds

Comment: Well, how can I solve this?

Comment: Is this your server or is it a hosted server

Comment: @RiggsFolly this is localhost

Comment: What you are cURLing to is not `curl_init("https://webexapis.com/v1/meetings");`